# Как правильнее написать цикл или условие

Tags: c#, строки

Ввести 3 строки, если совпадает длина строки то вывести в новую строку подряд по каждой букве c#, длины строк могут быть разными, как аккуратней написать код под каждую ситуацию типа длина совпадает у 1ой и 2ой,2ой и 3ой, 1ой и 3ой, не расписывая каждый вариант как снизу

```
string a = textBox1.Text;
string b = textBox2.Text;
string c = textBox3.Text;
string result = "";
if (a.Length == b.Length && b.Length == c.Length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        result += $"{a[i]}" + $"{b[i]}"  + $"{c[i]}";
    }
} 
listBox1.Items.Add(result);
```

Comment: Зачем вы влепили метку "функциональное программирование"?

Comment: Условие написано правильно. Не надо ничего менять.

Comment: `result += $"{a[i]}{b[i]}{c[i]}";` - так короче. У вас зачем-то используется и конкатенация, и интерполяция. | Можно ещё, конечно, StringBuilder применить, но в данном случае это избыточно.

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = "";
var max_len = Math.Max(Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length), c.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < max_len; i++)
{
    if (i < a.Length)
    {
        result += a[i];
    }
    if (i < b.Length)
    {
        result += b[i];
    }
    if (i < c.Length)
    {
        result += c[i];
    }
}
```